# How comment script tag content in blade.php?

Tags: php, reactjs, laravel

I try build a React Laravel webpage.

The main.blade.php responsible the layout and that **pass data** and **React components** to other blade

I test my app and make few blade.php

So I try comment out several way this line:

```
 /*  const data =  {{ Illuminate\Support\Js::from($data)}};*/
```

but not work. It still perceives it as if it were there

I have to pass data for every route for testing because I can't comment the above line

```
Route::get('/react', function () {
  $data = User::find(1);
  return view('reactpractice', compact("data"));
})->name('react');
```

main.blade.php

```
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/app.css"/>
    <title>@yield('title')</title>
    <title>{{env('APP_NAME')}}</title>
</head>

<body>
   
<header>
    Motto
</header>

<nav>
    <a href="/">Index</a>
    <a href="/about">About</a>
    <a href="{{route('react')}}">React</a>
    <a href="{{route('users')}}">Users</a>
    <a href="{{route('login')}}">Login</a>
    <a href="{{route('register')}}">Register</a>
</nav>

    
    @yield('contenttop')
    @if(Session::has('successmessage'))
    <div class="alert alert-success my-3">
    {{Session::get('successmessage')}}
    </div>
    @endif

    @yield('example')
    <script>
     const data =  {{ Illuminate\Support\Js::from($data)}};
     const token = '{{@csrf_token()}}'
    </script>
    <h2> React</h2>
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

So how comment script tag content in blade.php?

Comment: Laravel Blade has its own Comment syntax: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/blade#comments, does it work with that?

Answer (score 2):

Rather than comment the line in JavaScript, why not make it conditional?

```
@if (isset($data))
const data =  {{ Illuminate\Support\Js::from($data)}};
@endif
```

This way, if $data is provided, the JavaScript variable will be created. If $data is missing, it will be ignored and won't break your code.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!-- Try like this -->
// or /* */
```

I hope it was helpfull.

Comment: It also not work but thank you

Comment: oooh sorry to hear that.
After commented out the line with '//', did you try press CTRL+F5? maybe its just a cache problem, happens sometimes OR you can try 'php artisan optimize' its clear the cache files too. maybe this is more helpfull

Comment: `{{ ... }}` is Blade (PHP) syntax, and can't be commented out with HTML comments; this has nothing to do with refreshing, using different comments (`//` vs `<!-- -->`, `/* ... */`, etc.), or caching, it's a quirk of the templating engine.

Comment: I try comment out as js and as HTML also but not success